# Generador de Numeración mensual C#

Tags: c#, mysql

Estoy tratando de crear un contador que se renueve cada mes basándose en el último registro almacenado en `SQL`, que comience con el prefijo `año-mes (aamm)`, y luego la numeración. Por ejemplo, ahora en julio de 2017 sería:

```
170700001, 170700002, 170700003
```

y así sucesivamente hasta agosto que pasaría a ser:

```
 170800001, 170800002, 170800003, etc...
```

La idea es almacenarlo en una tabla SQL e ir leyendo el último agregado a la hora de insertar uno nuevo. ¡Desde ya muchas gracias!

Comment: no voy a preguntar para que, aunque no suene logico.. el tema seria a la hora de agregar un nuevo registro.. esto anda en red o algo asi?

Comment: Me parece que tu mismo te estas dando la respuesta a tu pregunta. Cuando vayas a hacer un Insert vas a obtener el ID de dónde lo tengas almacenado, antes de realizar en Insert comprueba que el formato del ID es correcto (es decir, el año y el mes son los correctos), si es correcto procede a hacer el Insert con el contador +1, y haces Update al contador. Si no son correctos, crea el nuevo contador con el año y el mes actual y así con todo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El proceso no se ve complicado, yo lo haría de la siguiente manera:

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
int _cuantos = 0;
string _cuenta;

/*
 * Hacer una consulta escalar con el siguiente filtro:
 * "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ... WHERE Contador LIKE '" + now.ToString("yyMM") + "%' ORDER BY Contador DESC";
 * Por ejemplo:
 * _cuantos = int.Parse(query.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
 */

_cuenta = string.Format("{0:yyMM}{1:00000}", now, ++_cuantos);

/*
 * Hacer el INSERT usando como parámetro la string "_cuenta".
 */
```

Te dejo una nota sobre [cuándo usar ExecuteNonQuery o ExecuteScalar](http://elguille.info/net/adonet/cuando_usar_ExecuteNonQuery_o_ExecuteScalar.htm) para que sepas a qué me refiero con la *consulta escalar*. :D

Answer (score 0):

Create una tabla de parámetros en la BBDD:

```
Parametro Valor
Mes       7
Valor     1
```

Si lo vas a utilizar mucho, cárgalos al abrir el programa en la aplicación (variables mes y valorID por ejemplo), la estructura de la función podría ser algo así:

```
DateTime moment= DateTime.Now;
int year = moment.Year;
int month = moment.Month;
string yearS = moment.ToString("yy");
string monthS = moment.Month.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0');
Console.WriteLine(cadenaID);
if(month!=mes)
{
mes=month; 
valorID=1;
//Y actualizar en BBDD los parametros
}
string valorIDs=(valorID.ToString()).PadLeft(5, '0');
string cadenaID=yearS+monthS+valorIDs;

valorID++;//También actualizar el valor en BBDD tras el incremento
```

Saludos